# How to correlate drop down list

Tags: jmeter, correlation

I have a response like below-

```
"distributionChannelList":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "description":"Agency1"
    },
    {
        "id":5,
        "description":"Agency2"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "description":"Agency3"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "description":"Agency4"
    }
],
"marketingTypeList":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "description":"Type1".......
```

There are so many 'id' and 'description' values in my response. Agency1, Agency2.. are drop downs in my application.

So I want Jmeter to pick a different agency every time and pass in subsequent requests.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use json extractor or reg Ex to fetch all the description with Match No. as 0 for random. Pass the Json created variable to the next request like ${varDescription}. On every run, random value will be fetched and provided to the next request.

Below snapshot is an example for regex but prefer json in your case. For fetching with json use $..description as json path expression. Repeat the same for others if required.
[image]

Hope this helps.

**Update:-**
Please check the below config. It will extractor 2 values in sync. But, ${cnt} should be same value. I have used counter just for demo. You can use random function to generate value between 1 to 4 and pass that variable ${rnd};${rnd}.
[image]

Comment: With that regular expression, description from marketingTypeList will also be considered right!? But I want only from distributionChannelList.

Comment: $..description will fetch all description including marketingTypeList

Comment: I don't want marketingTypeList.. only distributionChannelList is required

Comment: $.distributionChannelList..description should only fetch from distribution channel list.But if something is before that then you may need to modified it. Please check examples provided here...https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/03/09/how-to-extract-data-from-json-response-using-jmeter/

Comment: Above info was useful, Thanks!! Now I am able to get both 'id' and 'description' from the response in this format {"description":"Agency4","id":3}. But the problem is, in the request those 2 values are going separately as below. How to break the response and past the separately?                  "distributionChannel": {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "Agency"
      },

Comment: Use 2 json extractor, one for description and one for id. Then, pass two variables to the next request. If only there is no dependency between two and random values can be passed to the next request.

Comment: Dependency is there here. That is the problem. If we pick an agency, the respective id value should also be sent in the request. So using 2 jason extractors will not guarantee this behavior.

Comment: Two options, I can think of, Use JSR223 Post processor and then write code to fetch the required value from json extractor variable. This require some coding. 2nd..You can use dummy sampler and in the response pass json extractor variable ${var_json} then use reg Ex postprocessor under dummay to extract two required values. As I am not good with groovy, I dont have the code ready. Do ask this as a question to get quick response from experts

Comment: Check the update. Also, Please check this :-https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  . It help others.